# Jersey service - getEntity not working

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jersey-client

It does not work the following service:

XML return

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order>
<id>
<![CDATA[ 1 ]]>
</id>
<date_add>
<![CDATA[ 2014-08-22 16:26:15 ]]>
</date_add>
</order>
</prestashop>
```

Class VO

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlCDATA;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="prestashop")
public class Pedido {

    @XmlCDATA public Integer id=null;
    @XmlCDATA public String date_add=null;                  //Fecha creación

}
```

Java client

```
import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;


public class ClienteRest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    Pedido pedido = new Pedido();

    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("WZWVR59997VL4BMKDV99C7GA1RBYGGBF", ""));

    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
    // Get XML
    System.out.println(service.path("orders").path("1").accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ClientResponse.class));
    ClientResponse response = service.path("orders").path("1").accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);
    // Get XML for application
    Pedido oPedido = response.getEntity(pedido.getClass());

    System.out.println(oPedido.total_paid);

  }

  private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://WZWVR59997VL4BMKDV99C7GA1RBYGGBF@example.com/api").build();
  }

}
```

This is the output of java program

GET http://WZWVR59997VL4BMKDV99C7GA1RBYGGBF@example.com/api/orders/1 returned a response status of 200 OK
null

I want to recover the object class Order of XML does not work when getEntity always returns null

Answer (score 0):

The VO class does not seem to match the xml, xml seems to represent the following VO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="prestashop")
public class Pedido {

    private Order order;

    public Order getOrder(){
       return order;
     }

    public void setOrder(Order o){
        order = o;
    }
}
public class Order {

    @XmlCDATA public Integer id=null;
    @XmlCDATA public String date_add=null;                  

}
```